# how to manage CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

this is my ability.rb

```
class Ability

 include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
  end
  end
```

and index

```
  <% if can? :update, @post %>
      <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                  edit_post_path(post), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
      <% end %>
```

but I recive error

"NoMethodError in Posts#index undefined method `admin?' for #"

where should I define admin or other roles? And how can i choose admin or anoher role when sign in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create admin method in User model

```
def admin?
  type == 'Admin'
end
```

This is in case you have Admin model:

```
class Admin < User
end
```

Comment: You have to add a type column to users, google for single table inheritance, will make the things clear for you.

Comment: I have any Admin model but create now and define admin method in User. Now i recive "NameError in Posts#index undefined local variable or method `type' for #<User:0x007f76dc828d90>"

Comment: `rails g migration AddTypeToUser type:string` then `rake db:migrate`. Any existing users that are supposed to me admins will need their type updated manually. `user = User.find(id_of_admin); user.update_column('type','Admin');`